# React Material UI: How to give a button a custom color when disabled?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a React App using Material UI.

If the button is disabled, it is grey and opaque. I'd like it to be in my themes primary color and opaque.

So here is what I tried:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    ":disabled": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary || 'red'
    }
  }
});

function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        disabled
        className={classes.button}
      >
        Disabled
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

ContainedButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ContainedButtons);
```

But the button stays grey. How can you change the style of a disabled element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a class to be applied for disabled buttons:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  disabledButton: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary || 'red'
  }
});
```

And then, use it like this:

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  disabled
  classes={{ disabled: classes.disabledButton }}
>
  Disabled
</Button>
```

You can find in the [documentation all the classes](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css) that you can override.

Comment: I like this approach, but unfortunately I believe that it does not actually work (though if I am wrong I would love to see the sandbox). To get it to work you need to follow the (unintuitive) method [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet).

Comment: this does not work... must use the `jss-nested` method

Comment: This answer is from 2019. It might be that it's not valid anymore with the current version of MUI.

Answer (score 35):

Or you can try `createMuiTheme` and customize the following property:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    action: {
      disabledBackground: 'set color of background here',
      disabled: 'set color of text here'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is correct! I would add also
`
palette: {
  action: {
    disabled: YourCustomColor
  }
}`

Comment: Not working for me!

Answer (score 14):

Ran into the same issue and managed to solve it by changing `:disabled` to `&:disabled`.

```
    const styles = theme => ({
      button: {
        "&:disabled": {
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary || 'red'
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

Neps answer is correct, but I will add more details.

First of all you should import createMuiTheme and ThemeProvider:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

Create theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    action: {
      disabledBackground: 'set color of background here',
      disabled: 'set color of text here'
    }
  }
});
```

And wrap your button:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Button color="primary">Primary</Button>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: How `disabledBackground` is being used?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to use the `sx` prop:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Button
      disabled
      variant="contained"
      sx={{
        "&.Mui-disabled": {
          background: "#eaeaea",
          color: "#c0c0c0"
        }
      }}
    >
      Disabled Button
    </Button>
  );
}
```

But using MIU theme will make the changes persist globally without having to style it again

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&.Mui-disabled": {
            background: "#f3f3f3",
            color: "#dadada"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button disabled variant="contained">
        Disabled Button
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

You even customize it based on the selected variant:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState }) => {
          switch (ownerState.variant) {
            case "contained":
              return {
                "&.Mui-disabled": {
                  background: "#f3f3f3",
                  color: "#dadada"
                }
              };
            case "outlined":
              return {
                "&.Mui-disabled": {
                  background: "#e9e9e9",
                  color: "#c7c7c7",
                  borderColor: "#e4e4e4"
                }
              };
            default:
              return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Below is a more detailed tutorial about customizing disabled button colors:

https://muhimasri.com/blogs/customizing-disabled-button-colors-with-mui/

Answer (score 7):

You can add styling to buttons disabled class like:

`.Mui-disabled { background-color: blue; }`

You can also see what other classes you can use to style button on https://material-ui.com/api/button/

Answer (score 4):

I was using Styled-Components in my project so I used that as follows:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

const MyButton = styled(Button)`
  &&& {
    &.Mui-disabled {
      color: #fff;
      background: #000;
    }
  }
`;

<MyButton>I am styled button</MyButton>
```