# React Materials-UI disable a button in a handler

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to disable a button after the user clicks on it, but from a handler function.

I have referenced these two similar questions:
[React Material UI: How to give a button a custom color when disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586626/react-material-ui-how-to-give-a-button-a-custom-color-when-disabled/56520516)
[Change disable attribute in react select with material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637567/change-disable-attribute-in-react-select-with-material-ui)

I thought changing the color would be a good practice step, but that didn't work.  When I use color='primary' the button is blue, and that's what I want for the initial state.  However, when the page loads, the button is now gray (looks disabled, but the mouse can still click on it).

My original blue button:

```
 <Button id='UploadButton' onClick={uploadButtonClicked} 
         variant="contained" color="primary">Upload</Button>
```

My revised button (trying to use state for color):

```
 <Button id='UploadButton' onClick={uploadButtonClicked} 
         disabled="{uploadButtonDisabled}" 
         variant="contained" 
         color="{uploadButtonColor}">Upload</Button>
```

My state & handler:

```
       const [uploadButtonColor, setUploadButtonColor] =
React.useState('primary');   
       const [uploadButtonDisabled,
setUploadButtonDisabled] = React.useState('false');
      
       const uploadButtonClicked = () => {
          // will post data to a REST API here, then disable the button 
          setUploadButtonColor('red')
          setUploadButtonDisabled('true')
      }
```

Do I need to use color schema to make it look disabled, or can I just add the disabled word, or set disabled to true?

This is how [the doc](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) shows a disabled button:

```
<Button variant="outlined" disabled>
    Upload 
</Button>
```

Comment: There are some extra curly brackets for color prop: `<Button id='UploadButton' onClick={uploadButtonClicked} variant="contained" color="{{UploadButtonColor}}">Upload</Button>` needs to be changed to this: `<Button id='UploadButton' onClick={uploadButtonClicked} variant="contained" color={UploadButtonColor}>Upload</Button>`.

Comment: Thanks but same result, I've tried both.  And the primary question is how to disable.  Changing color was just a step to getting there.

Comment: To disable just set `disabled` property to boolean, like so `disabled={false}`. You can use some variable from your state but you still need to use singe braces without quotes to interpolate variable. This one won't work: `color="{{UploadButtonColor}}"` this is just string, React wont interpolate it. It should be inside single braces, like your `onClick` handler

Comment: See updates to my question above.  I removed the double {{.  Does disabled take a true/false?  See what I tried.  When the form loads, why it the button white on gray?

Comment: Yes, `disabled` takes boolean. You still left quotes though. `disabled="{uploadButtonDisabled}"` remove quotes and change to `disabled={uploadButtonDisabled}`. Button is grey because there is no "red" color defined for your current theme. Try to use 'secondary' instead of red, for example.

Comment: I tried true/false without the single quotes as well. Does it need to be a boolean, or just the string? Capital or lower case?

Comment: Just boolean, not the string. Without quotes. Like so `setUploadButtonDisabled(true)` and `React.useState(false);`

Comment: Tried that too, no difference.

Comment: I've made working example for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions63678017-5qpns?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know we could use material-ui in a sandbox app. One of my issues was the quote around the {values}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not put quotes around the property/substitution values
disabled={isDisabled} not disabled='{isDisabled}' (and same with color).

You can use this :

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function SampleButtons(props) {
  let [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setIsDisabled(true)} disabled={isDisabled}>Button</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think I got it now.  Why wouldn't disabled={isDisabled} be specified as this: disabled="{isDisabled}".  I did check the console log and saw a few error I didn't check before.

Comment: If you do ` disabled="{isDisabled}"` you set the prop as a string. You want to pass `isDisabled` as a variable