# How to disable button of metarial UI after one click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to disable a button in my react project, where I have used MUI css framework. But now I want to know how can I disable button after one click.

```
<Button variant="contained" 
  onClick={()=>handleAdd(course)}
disabled=?
>
```

Comment: Have you even tried to find it ? [React Materials-UI disable a button in a handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678017/react-materials-ui-disable-a-button-in-a-handler)

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a new state using useState hook named for example isClicked and change your handleAdd function to set the state to true after a click.

```
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
```

Then in your handleAdd method add something like:

```
if(!isClicked) setIsClicked(true)
```

And finaly in your Button component, set disabled to this state.

```
disabled = {isClicked}
```

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

```
disabled={currentGroupForm.name?.length === 0 ||
    currentGroupForm.sapNumber?.length === 0 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.